# Calling a virtual function statically through a function pointer

Tags: c++, static, virtual

Please consider the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
  A() {}
  virtual void f() {
    std::cout << "A::f" << std::endl;
  }
private:
  A(const A&);
};

struct B : public A {
  virtual void f() {
    std::cout << "B::f" << std::endl;
    call(&A::f);
  }
private:
  void call(void (A::*aMethod)()) {
    // ...
    (static_cast<A&>(*this).*aMethod)();
    //(static_cast<A>(*this).*aMethod)();  -> not allowed to copy!
    // ...
  }
};

void main() {
  std::auto_ptr<B> b (new B);
  b->f();
}
```

This code recursively calls the same `B::f` method until it runs out of stack, while I would like the `call` method to call `A::f`. That is, it should call it statically as it would normally happen had I simply written:

```
struct B : public A {
  virtual void f() {
    std::cout << "B::f" << std::endl;
    // ...
    A::f();
    // ...
  }
};
```

The reason I want to have the `call` method is to factor some code before and after the 'static call' that is common to several methods with the same signature as `f`...

How can I statically call a virtual function decided at run-time?

Comment: In `B::f`, why do you have to call the function through `call` and a function pointer? Why can't you just do `A::f();` ?  (Refactoring the "before" and "after" code into some common functions or a common class.)

Comment: That's probably what I'll have to do... Method `call` was just here to factor out the code, but I had not realized I would not be able to use it as I intended to...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's expected. The object expression is a Reference to the Base class A and hence virtual function mechanism (dynamic binding) is triggered as A::f is virtual.

Only the :: operator can supperess virtual function call mechanism.

> $10.3/12- "Explicit qualification with
>   the scope operator (5.1) suppresses
>   the virtual call mechanism."

Comment: And it seems I can't use the scope operator here: it would qualify the name of the pointer, not the function pointed to...

Comment: Yes, AFAICT, you will have to go with A::f

Answer (score 1):

Your override is resolved when you take the pointer, so what you want here is not easily possible this way. The best thing you can do is a wrapper that calls your function - either something external, or a non-virtual function that calls your function. If you have C++0x features, you could use a lambda which is the cleanest solution IMO.

You might wanna rethink the way you do pre/post-functions as another way to tackle your problem: They can be implemented by overloading the "->" operator.

Comment: Unfortunately, overloading operator-> is not applicable in the real case because it would apply to any method called, not just to f and the others that are similar... But thanks anyway...

Comment: Yes, that is usually a problem. However, maybe you can refactor your code to put just those methods into a seperate interface class. Or just apply the wrapping operator on the call-site of your virtual functions like

  Call(myObject)->f();

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to overload -> for that last idea. Just implementing ctor and dtor of a "Call" type will suffice.